# Groupby, shift and forward fill

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this df:

```
ID         Date   Time       Lat       Lon
 A  07/16/2019   08:00  29.39291 -98.50925
 A  07/16/2019   09:00  29.39923 -98.51256
 A  07/16/2019   10:00  29.40147 -98.51123
 A  07/18/2019   08:30  29.38752 -98.52372
 A  07/18/2019   09:30  29.39291 -98.50925
 B  07/16/2019   08:00  29.39537 -98.50402
 B  07/18/2019   11:00  29.39343 -98.49707
 B  07/18/2019   12:00  29.39291 -98.50925
 B  07/19/2019   10:00  29.39556 -98.53148
```

I want to group the df by `ID` and `Date`, shift the rows one step backward, and fill the NaN values with forward filling.

Note: `(ID, Date)` with only one row, should be filled by the row itself.

For example: `B  07/16/2019   08:00  29.39537 -98.50402`

Expected result:

```
ID         Date   Time       Lat       Lon Time.1     Lat.1     Lon.1
 A  07/16/2019   08:00  29.39291 -98.50925  09:00  29.39923 -98.51256
 A  07/16/2019   09:00  29.39923 -98.51256  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123
 A  07/16/2019   10:00  29.40147 -98.51123  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123
 A  07/18/2019   08:30  29.38752 -98.52372  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925
 A  07/18/2019   09:30  29.39291 -98.50925  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925
 B  07/16/2019   08:00  29.39537 -98.50402  08:00  29.39537 -98.50402
 B  07/18/2019   11:00  29.39343 -98.49707  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925
 B  07/18/2019   12:00  29.39291 -98.50925  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925
 B  07/19/2019   10:00  29.39556 -98.53148  10:00  29.39556 -98.53148
```

The code I'm using (which doesn't meet the expected result):

```
pd.concat([df, df.groupby(['ID','Date']).shift(-1).ffill()], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution if no missing values in original data - first replace rows with one element groups by original values and then forward filling missing values:

```
m = ~df.duplicated(['ID','Date']) & ~df.duplicated(['ID','Date'], keep=False)
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','Date']).shift(-1).mask(m, df).ffill()
df = pd.concat([df, df1.add_suffix('.1')], axis=1)
print (df)
  ID        Date   Time       Lat       Lon Time.1     Lat.1     Lon.1
0  A  07/16/2019  08:00  29.39291 -98.50925  09:00  29.39923 -98.51256
1  A  07/16/2019  09:00  29.39923 -98.51256  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123
2  A  07/16/2019  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123
3  A  07/18/2019  08:30  29.38752 -98.52372  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925
4  A  07/18/2019  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925
5  B  07/16/2019  08:00  29.39537 -98.50402  08:00  29.39537 -98.50402
6  B  07/18/2019  11:00  29.39343 -98.49707  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925
7  B  07/18/2019  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925
8  B  07/19/2019  10:00  29.39556 -98.53148  10:00  29.39556 -98.53148
```

If not necessary custom function then double `groupby` are necessary, because forward filling is necessary per groups:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','Date']).shift(-1).groupby([df['ID'],df['Date']]).ffill().fillna(df)
df = pd.concat([df, df1.add_suffix('.1')], axis=1)
print (df)
  ID        Date   Time       Lat       Lon Time.1     Lat.1     Lon.1
0  A  07/16/2019  08:00  29.39291 -98.50925  09:00  29.39923 -98.51256
1  A  07/16/2019  09:00  29.39923 -98.51256  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123
2  A  07/16/2019  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123
3  A  07/18/2019  08:30  29.38752 -98.52372  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925
4  A  07/18/2019  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925
5  B  07/16/2019  08:00  29.39537 -98.50402  08:00  29.39537 -98.50402
6  B  07/18/2019  11:00  29.39343 -98.49707  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925
7  B  07/18/2019  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925
8  B  07/19/2019  10:00  29.39556 -98.53148  10:00  29.39556 -98.53148
```

With lambda function should be solution like:

```
c = ['Time','Lat','Lon']
df1 = df.groupby(['ID','Date'])[c].apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1).ffill()).fillna(df)
df = pd.concat([df, df1.add_suffix('.1')], axis=1)
print (df)
  ID        Date   Time       Lat       Lon Time.1     Lat.1     Lon.1
0  A  07/16/2019  08:00  29.39291 -98.50925  09:00  29.39923 -98.51256
1  A  07/16/2019  09:00  29.39923 -98.51256  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123
2  A  07/16/2019  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123
3  A  07/18/2019  08:30  29.38752 -98.52372  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925
4  A  07/18/2019  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925
5  B  07/16/2019  08:00  29.39537 -98.50402  08:00  29.39537 -98.50402
6  B  07/18/2019  11:00  29.39343 -98.49707  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925
7  B  07/18/2019  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925
8  B  07/19/2019  10:00  29.39556 -98.53148  10:00  29.39556 -98.53148
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do:

```
def grp_col(f):
    f['Time.1'] = f['Time'].shift(-1).ffill().fillna(f['Time'].iloc[0])
    f['Lat.1'] = f['Lat'].shift(-1).ffill().fillna(f['Lat'].iloc[0])
    f['Lon.1'] = f['Lon'].shift(-1).ffill().fillna(f['Lon'].iloc[0])
    return f

df = df.groupby(['ID','Date'], as_index=False).apply(grp_col)
```

Comment: It works well. Is there a way to do so without a defined function?