# Groupby and apply a defined function - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this df:

```
ID         Date   Time       Lat       Lon Time_1     Lat_1     Lon_1
 A  07/16/2019   08:00  29.39291 -98.50925  09:00  29.39923 -98.51256
 A  07/16/2019   09:00  29.39923 -98.51256  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123
 A  07/16/2019   10:00  29.40147 -98.51123  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123
 A  07/18/2019   08:30  29.38752 -98.52372  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925
 A  07/18/2019   09:30  29.39291 -98.50925  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925
 B  07/16/2019   08:00  29.39537 -98.50402  08:00  29.39537 -98.50402
 B  07/18/2019   11:00  29.39343 -98.49707  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925
 B  07/18/2019   12:00  29.39291 -98.50925  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925
 B  07/19/2019   10:00  29.39556 -98.53148  10:00  29.39556 -98.53148
```

I want to creat `"Distance"` column by grouping the df by `ID` and `Date`, and to apply a defined function.

The code I wrote:

```
def grp_crossarc(f):

    for i in range(len(f)):

        f.loc[i,'Distance'] = crossarc(f.iloc[i]['Lat'],f.iloc[i]['Lon'],
                                         f.iloc[i]['Lat_1'],f.iloc[i]['Lat_1'],
                                         29.39537,-98.50402)
    return f

df.groupby(['ID','Date'],as_index=False).apply(grp_crossarc)
```

`crossarc` is another defined function that gets 6 arguments (3 lat-lon points).

The result I got:

```
  ID         Date   Time       Lat       Lon Time_1     Lat_1     Lon_1  Distance
   A  07/16/2019   08:00  29.39291 -98.50925  09:00  29.39923 -98.51256  0.166057
   A  07/16/2019   09:00  29.39923 -98.51256  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123  0.889147
   A  07/16/2019   10:00  29.40147 -98.51123  10:00  29.40147 -98.51123  0.973550
   A  07/18/2019   08:30  29.38752 -98.52372  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925       NaN
   A  07/18/2019   09:30  29.39291 -98.50925  09:30  29.39291 -98.50925       NaN
 NaN          NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  0.736501
 NaN          NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  0.165974
   B  07/16/2019   08:00  29.39537 -98.50402  08:00  29.39537 -98.50402       NaN
 NaN          NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  0.000000
   B  07/18/2019   11:00  29.39343 -98.49707  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925       NaN
   B  07/18/2019   12:00  29.39291 -98.50925  12:00  29.39291 -98.50925       NaN
 NaN          NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  0.707027
 NaN          NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  0.165974
   B  07/19/2019   10:00  29.39556 -98.53148  10:00  29.39556 -98.53148       NaN
 NaN          NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN    NaN       NaN       NaN  1.900238
```

For few `(ID, Date)` pairs, the Distance values shifted one row ahead, and therefore NaN values were created. How to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe perhaps this could help `df['col_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x.col_1, x.col_2), axis=1)` where `f` is the user defined function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try lambda function instead loop:

```
def grp_crossarc(f):
    f['Distance'] = (f.apply(lambda x: crossarc(x['Lat'],x['Lon'],
                                                x['Lat_1'],x['Lat_1'],
                                                29.39537,-98.50402), axis=1))
    return f

df = df.groupby(['ID','Date'],as_index=False).apply(grp_crossarc)
```

But it seems function is not dependent of groups, so should be simplify with omit `groupby.apply`:

```
df['Distance'] = (df.apply(lambda x: crossarc(x['Lat'],x['Lon'],
                                              x['Lat_1'],x['Lat_1'],
                                              29.39537,-98.50402), axis=1))
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. The function is not dependent on groups. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, do you have a solution for this (without a defined function): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59643503/groupby-shift-and-forward-fill ?

Comment: @qwerty - I try it, for first see possible, but better test.

Comment: @qwerty - I add 3 solutions ;)